# What German movie has a woman in prison holding a wire in her mouth to survive?

Tags: story-identification

I’m trying to identify a German sci-fi film that seemed to be based around a prison. It had lots of fetish wear in it. I saw it around 2000, so it’s from before that.

I think there was an escapee plot, with the two leads (male 30s / female 20s) also concerned with where they would go after they escaped.

The scene that I particularly remember is a predicament scene where a woman is holding a wire in her mouth and if she lets it go, she or someone else will die.

I realise this is a long shot but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What about this film is science fiction?

Comment: I seem to remember it being, very futuristic, and I am almost, but not certain, that is was on another planet

Comment: Do you remember any of the character's names, who the actor were, what the protagonist's goal was, any dialogue? Also, was the film an original german film (e.g. the dialogue was in german or was it dubbed?).

Comment: It's very fuzzy, and my German was (and is still) very spotty.  I think there was an escapee plot, with the two leads (male 30s / female 20s) also concerned with where they would go after they escaped.  Can't remember any more than that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is "[The Perils of Gwendoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Perils_of_Gwendoline_in_the_Land_of_the_Yik-Yak)". There's a strong futuristic element, a concrete prison underground and extensive wearing of leather fetishwear (oh, mercy).

There's also a scene where the female character is placed into an eleborate trap where she'll be shot if she lets go of an object placed in her mouth.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I could have sworn that it was set on another planet but The screen cap is spot on.  I see its in French, but I watched in German.   Thanks for this really quick response

Comment: And having a title enabled me to discover that there was a German dubbed release.   Thanks again.  Ebay here I come.