# Need help identifying 80's Scifi movie

Tags: story-identification

Trying to identify a movie where a man rescues a woman who is forced to hold onto a wire with her mouth. If she lets go a large spike will fly towards her.

Comment: Why is it sci-fi?

Comment: And does this involve a group in a jungle, kind of a post-apocolyptic feel, lots of traps involving things like swinging logs? I have this vague memory of a movie like that that included the woman (love interest of the protagonist I think) in such a situation.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63076/what-german-movie-has-a-woman-in-prison-holding-a-wire-in-her-mouth-to-survive)

Comment: @JoeL. policy is to not close story-id's as dupes [unless we have confirmed answers for both](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7065/5184).

Answer (score 3):

Per my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63076/20774), are you thinking of the French film "The Perils of Gwendoline"?